# ASP.NET page shows up as plain HTML-code

Tags: asp.net-2.0

So, I just started learning ASP.NET and I wanted to make a very simple website for a project I'm working on.

I made one page and published it via Visual Studio, but all it shows is plain HTML.

You can find it here:

http://www.limburgsewolven.host-ed.me/Default.aspx

Has somebody got any idea why it shows up like this? :s The host is supposed to be able to host ASP.NET 2.0, so that's what I used.

Thanks!

Comment: How are you hosting this file?  IE when I request it from the Url, what interprets my request ?

Comment: Looks like a IIS configuration issue. Is asp.net enabled?